# I really need help... I am looking for a solution about 28hours

Tags: posts, tags

I want to display articles with music tag(ID=24) to related post, so I added ('tag_in' => array( 24 ),).

Now, it displays the articles with music tag(ID=24) to related post correctly in post with music tag(ID=24) and HIP-HOP tag(ID=25).

But, when I create a new post with HIP-HOP tag(ID=25), the articles with music tag(ID=24) is displayed in related post.

Why the articles with music tag(ID=24) is displayed even though the post has only HIP-HOP tag(ID=25) ?

I want to display the articles with music tag(ID=24) only when the post has music tag(ID=24).

Maybe I need to add another code ?

TLDR; I want to display the articles with music tag to related post only when the post has music tag.

sorry for a bad english.

I hope you can understand what I wanna tell and I really need a solution.

```
// Get the taxonomy terms of the current page for the specified taxonomy.
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'post_tag', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

// Bail if the term empty.
if ( empty( $terms ) ) {
    return;
}

// Posts query arguments.
$query = array(
    'tag__in'      => array( 24 ),
    'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
    'tax_query'    => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $terms,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented same in one of my project requirement using functions "**wp_get_post_tags**" and "**get_posts**" to get related posts of same tags to which current post belongs to.

```
<?php
// Get tags of current post
$tag_objs = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
$tags = array();
foreach ($tag_objs as $tag_obj) {
    $tags[] = $tag_obj->term_id;
}

// Get Posts
$myposts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 6,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $tags,
        ),
     ),
    'post_status'=>'publish',
));?>
```

Hope this helps..!!

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. But, I dont know where should I insert this code. ;-( This is all PHP codes about related post. https://gyazo.com/dd08378547d073a9a925f664817a120b

Comment: @Taka The code is clearly an amended version of your existing code, so it would go in the same place as the code you already had.